# Mixing two audio files together with python

Tags: python, audio

I have two wav files that I want to mix together to form one wav file. They are both the same samples format etc...

Been searching google endlessly.

I would prefer to do it using the wave module in python.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 41):

You can use the [pydub](http://pydub.com) library (a light wrapper I wrote around the python wave module in the std lib) to do it pretty simply:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment

sound1 = AudioSegment.from_file("/path/to/my_sound.wav")
sound2 = AudioSegment.from_file("/path/to/another_sound.wav")

combined = sound1.overlay(sound2)

combined.export("/path/to/combined.wav", format='wav')
```

Comment: When I tried to do this only the sound that I was overlaying a different sound on was being heard. Is there a way to get around that?

Answer (score 10):

A python solution which requires both numpy and audiolab, but is fast and simple:

```
import numpy as np
from scikits.audiolab import wavread

data1, fs1, enc1 = wavread("file1.wav")
data2, fs2, enc2 = wavread("file2.wav")

assert fs1 == fs2
assert enc1 == enc2
result = 0.5 * data1 + 0.5 * data2
```

If sampling rate (fs*) or encoding (enc*) are different, you may need some audio processing (the assert are strictly speaking too strong, as wavread can handle some cases transparantly).

Comment: Shouldn't you `assert len(data1) == len(data2)` too? And you could also use `scipy` to read a wave file: `from scipy.io import wavfile` and then `fs, data = wavfile.read("file.wav")`.

Answer (score 10):

LIBROSA SOLUTION

```
import librosa
import IPython as ip

y1, sample_rate1 = librosa.load(audio1, mono=True)
y2, sample_rate2 = librosa.load(audio2, mono=True)

# MERGE
librosa.display.waveplot((y1+y2)/2, sr=int((sample_rate1+sample_rate2)/2))

# REPRODUCE
ip.display.Audio((y1+y2)/2, rate=int((sample_rate1+sample_rate2)/2))
```

Answer (score 9):

You guys like `numpy`, no?   Below is a solution that depends on `wave` and `numpy`.  Raw bytes in two files './file1.wav' and './file2.wav' are added.  It's probably good to apply `np.clip` to `mix` before converting back to int-16 (not included).

```
import wave
import numpy as np
# load two files you'd like to mix
fnames =["./file1.wav", "./file2.wav"]
wavs = [wave.open(fn) for fn in fnames]
frames = [w.readframes(w.getnframes()) for w in wavs]
# here's efficient numpy conversion of the raw byte buffers
# '<i2' is a little-endian two-byte integer.
samples = [np.frombuffer(f, dtype='<i2') for f in frames]
samples = [samp.astype(np.float64) for samp in samples]
# mix as much as possible
n = min(map(len, samples))
mix = samples[0][:n] + samples[1][:n]
# Save the result
mix_wav = wave.open("./mix.wav", 'w')
mix_wav.setparams(wavs[0].getparams())
# before saving, we want to convert back to '<i2' bytes:
mix_wav.writeframes(mix.astype('<i2').tobytes())
mix_wav.close()
```

Comment: A great code! It is better to divide the result in mix line: ```mix = (samples[0][:n] + samples[1][:n])/2```

Answer (score 4):

this is very dependent of the format these are in. Here's an example of how to do it assuming 2 byte wide, little-endian samples:

```
import wave

w1 = wave.open("/path/to/wav/1")
w2 = wave.open("/path/to/wav/2")

#get samples formatted as a string.
samples1 = w1.readframes(w1.getnframes())
samples2 = w2.readframes(w2.getnframes())

#takes every 2 bytes and groups them together as 1 sample. ("123456" -> ["12", "34", "56"])
samples1 = [samples1[i:i+2] for i in xrange(0, len(samples1), 2)]
samples2 = [samples2[i:i+2] for i in xrange(0, len(samples2), 2)]

#convert samples from strings to ints
def bin_to_int(bin):
    as_int = 0
    for char in bin[::-1]: #iterate over each char in reverse (because little-endian)
        #get the integer value of char and assign to the lowest byte of as_int, shifting the rest up
        as_int <<= 8
        as_int += ord(char) 
    return as_int

samples1 = [bin_to_int(s) for s in samples1] #['\x04\x08'] -> [0x0804]
samples2 = [bin_to_int(s) for s in samples2]

#average the samples:
samples_avg = [(s1+s2)/2 for (s1, s2) in zip(samples1, samples2)]
```

And now all that's left to do is convert `samples_avg` back to a binary string and write that to a file using `wave.writeframes`. That's just the inverse of what we just did, so it shouldn't be too hard to figure out. For your int_to_bin function, you'll probably what to make use of the function `chr(code)`, which returns the character with the character code of `code` (opposite of ord)

Comment: Why Average of samples not Max? As far as I understand you can normally hear the loudest amplitude at given time

Answer (score 0):

Try the Echo Nest Remix API:

```
from echonest import audio
from util import *

def mixSound(fname1,fname2,f_out_name):

  f1 = audio.AudioData(fnem1)
  f2 = audio.AudioData(fnem2)


  f_out = audio.mix(f1,f2)
  f_out.encode(foutnem, True)
```

If it complains about codecs, check https://superuser.com/questions/196857/how-to-install-libmp3lame-for-ffmpeg.