# Merging multiple audio files

Tags: python, audio, merge, wav

I'm at very beginning in programming, and I'm studying Python. I want to make a little piece of software who looks into a directory with audio files, and merge them into a single audio file. 
Here is my current code:

```
import glob
#import os
import wave

fil = raw_input("Qual o diretorio ?")
#files = os.listdir(fil)
files = glob.glob(fil)

infiles = files
outfile = "merged.wav"

data= []
for infile in range(len(infiles)):
    w = wave.open(infile, 'rb')
    data.append([w.getparams(), w.readframes(w.getnframes())])
    w.close()

output = wave.open(outfile, 'wb')
output.setparams(data[0][0])
output.writeframes(data[0][1])
output.writeframes(data[1][1])
output.close()
```

I've based the code on this post [merging two wav files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4039158/mixing-two-audio-files-together-with-python). My idea was to use glob to populate an array, and iterate to get all the files but I'm getting an attribute error. 
What could I do?

Comment: You should always post the whole error with all the lines that could help us.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your advice. This is what i've got :                                            Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "merger.py", line 17, in <module>
    w = wave.open(infile, 'rb')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\wave.py", line 509, in open
    return Wave_read(f)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\wave.py", line 164, in __init__
    self.initfp(f)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\wave.py", line 129, in initfp
    self._file = Chunk(file, bigendian = 0)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\chunk.py", line 61, in __init__
    self.chunkname = file.read(4)

Comment: The error is missing. And it would be good if that is in your question since we look specifically for this and formatting makes it easier. Something like "AttributeError: xxx has no attribute yyy"

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that looks wrong is this:

```
for infile in range(len(infiles)):
```

You want to use this instead:

```
for infile in infiles:
```

I recommend using a debugger, like pudb (for Linux/Mac) or winpdb (Windows.